# Showing properties of a specific maximization problem, as well as finding the maximum.

Tags: analysis, optimization, lagrange-multiplier

Let there be $p_1,p_2,..,p_n,q_1,q_2,...,q_n$ with $\sum_{i=1}^n p_i = 1 = \sum_{i=1}^nq_i$

For $M :=\{ x\in (0,\infty)^n: \sum_{i=1}^nq_ix_i = a \}$

With the following Maximization Problem.

$$(*) \sup \bigg\{\sum_{i=1}^np_i\ln (x_i) : x \in M \bigg \}$$

(i) I need to show: $\forall\eta >0$ $$\sup_{r>0}(\ln(r) -\eta r) = \ln(\frac{1}{\eta})-1$$

(ii) I also need to show: $\forall x\in M$ and $\forall \eta > 0$ $$\sum_{i=0}^np_i\ln(x_i) \leq \sum_{i=0}^np_i\ln(\frac{p_i}{\eta q_i}) + a\eta -1 $$

(iii) I need to also show, that for the problem $(*)$ there is a maximizer $x^*\in M$ and to determine it's value.

I currently have no idea how to approach this, as this is my first maximization problem. For now i know that for the maximizer i can use the Lagrange-Method to obtain the maximum of this function. But for the issues (i) and (ii) i got a bit more trouble figuring out what i need to do.

Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

i) Take the first derivative of the function $f(r)=ln(r)-\eta r$ then do some calculation.

ii) Using i) with $r=x_i$ and $\eta=\dfrac{\eta q_i}{p_i}$ then multiple with $p_i$ and sum up all the inequality.

iii) Notice that in ii) equality happens when $x_i=\dfrac{p_i}{\eta q_i}$. We need $\displaystyle\sum_{i=1}^n q_i x_i=a$, which is equivalent to $\eta =\dfrac{1}{a}$. Therefore, by just taking  $\eta =\dfrac{1}{a}$ in ii), we're done.

Comment: A question about your i) i wanted to know what to do after the derivative. Other than that i am set.

Comment: You will see the sign of the derivative $f’(r)$ then you can compare the value of the function $f(r)$.

Comment: So when $f'(r) =\frac{1}{r}-\eta$  has a sign of -1 for all $\eta > 0$ For comparing the value of the function you do mean $\ln(\frac{1}{\eta}) -1$ I just do not quite understand the i) yet. Other than that the other things are quite followable. thanks for the help though. I appreciate it.

Comment: The sign of derivative is + if $r<1/\eta$ and - otherwise. So the maximum of the function $f(r)$ is that value you mention. Btw. You’re welcome.

Comment: Thanks a lot again !

Comment: One last question. In iii) My calculations lead me to $\sum_{i=0}^np_i \ln(\frac{p_ia}{q_i})$ Where should it lead so i can find my $x^*$. I currently am confused on that calcuation.

Comment: If I understand ur question. Then the inequality comes from ii) and the equality condition comes from i) and the constraint.